# android native calendar app get notified OF what is the current date displayed to user on the calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

i want my app be notified of the month and week that the user navigate on the calendar app so that when the user navigate to a month that doesn't have my app appointments i can load these appointments and update the calendar.

Comment: if there any broadcast receiver for the navigation on the months and weeks of the native calendar app in order that update my app to load the data of these month if it is not exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there any broadcast receiver for the navigation on the months and weeks of the native calendar app in order that update my app to load the data of these month if it is not exist ?

No.